# LEFT JOIN, INNER OUTER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN is driving me crazy. Please help?

Tags: users, wpdb, user-meta

fellow coders! I an having a hard time JOIN(ing) tables.

I have a a lot of users on my site and many of them have the same last names. I am trying to get their emails by their last name. WP stores emails in the users table and user names in the usermeta and I have been trying to use JOIN to get what I want, but I don't understand how it works and I am about to give up for the day. 
This is what i have after 4.5 hours.

```
$usersemails = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT users.user_email, usermeta.meta_value 
FROM $wpdb->users
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta ON $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id 
    WHERE user_status = '0' 
    AND meta_value = 'Smith'");
```

Any help is appreciated, so can you please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@Holidaymaine**:

Not sure where you are doing wrong, but try the following instead which is a self contained `test.php` file you can drop into the root of your website and load in your browser with `http://yoursite.com/test.php` *(assuming you replace `yoursite.com` with your site's domain! Also, note how I adding in a `WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'last_name'` to ensure you did not get records you were not expecting):*

```
<?php
/*
Filename: test.php
*/

include('wp-load.php');

$sql =<<<SQL
SELECT
  {$wpdb->users}.user_email,
  {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value
FROM
  {$wpdb->users}
  LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND {$wpdb->users}.user_status = '0'
  AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'last_name'
  AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value = 'Smith'
SQL;
  $usersemails = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  header('Content-type:text/plain');
  print_r($usersemails);
```

Comment: Thank you Mike! This worked perfectly. I will have to compare it with what I was doing to learn a more about JOIN. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Holidaymaine - Don't forget to select a best answer; mine, or one of the others. We work for reputation here! :)

Comment: Still learning how this site works :)  Can you help me join another table? I just realized I need to know if their post is related to a taxonomy term, so I can get the email if their posts have the term in it.

Comment: @Holidaymaine - Actually, for new questions the correct protocol for the site is to **[ask another question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)**.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that, I will read the FAQ again.  I did and here is the link if you would like to help. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/i-need-help-joining-one-or-more-tables

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via API, user search got improved in 3.1

```
$search = new WP_User_Query(array(
             'meta_value' => 'Lastname',
             'fields' => array('user_email'),
                ));

var_dump($search->get_results());
```

Comment: This did not work, but thanks for letting me know about the improved search. I will be looking into it for future use. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't vote this up.

Comment: @Holidaymaine I tested the snippet so it should work... What exactly not worked for you? Also don't forget to change `Lastname` to actual last name you are searching for.

Comment: I have to apologize Rarst, after trying a few  WP_User_Query myself I realized it wasn't your code, but another code before it that was causing the problem. It was returning an array with everything about the users except the emails and  user IDs. Thank you for letting me know about this function and your code does work. I have no idea how to remove my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT users.user_email, usermeta.meta_value`

Should be:

`SELECT $wpdb->users.user_email, $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value`

Prefixes matter.