# $wpdb - joining shows no result

Tags: wpdb, join-tables

For one of my client's WP site, I'm making a plugin, where I'm using the db Query. I've two custom tables dedicated to the plugin:

- **user_req** — stores user chosen posts along with some custom fields' data.
- **user_req_admin** — stores some very basic things, with a special foreign key `user_req_id`.

**Table: user_req**
[image: user_req view]

**Table: user_req_admin**
[image: user_req_admin view]

My plan is to **Join 5 tables** with a single query:

1. user_req
2. user_req_admin
3. posts
4. postmeta
5. users

Joining will be done by:

- `{$wpdb->user_req_admin}.user_req_id` connects by `{$wpdb->user_req}.id` (Connects both the db with User Request ID)
- `{$wpdb->user_req}.user_id` connects by `{$wpdb->users}.ID` (Fetch the User details using user_id)
- `{$wpdb->user_req}.post_id` connects by `{$wpdb->posts}.ID` (Fetch the Posts details using the `post_id`s in an array)
- `{$wpdb->user_req}.post_id` connects by `{$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id` (Fetch the Custom Fields using the `post_id`s in an array)

But for a startup, I tried joining the first two tables (#1 and #2), and eventually Failed!

Here's how I tried:

```
global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->print_error();
    $inbox_query = "SELECT
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.id,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.dt_usr_sent,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.dt_usr_rcvd,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.user_id,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.post_id,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.qty,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.msg_user,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.msg_admin,
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.price,
                          {$wpdb->user_req_admin}.user_req_id
                        FROM
                          {$wpdb->user_req}
                        LEFT JOIN
                          {$wpdb->user_req_admin}
                        ON
                          {$wpdb->user_req}.id = {$wpdb->user_req_admin}.user_req_id";
    $inbox_rows = $wpdb->get_results( $inbox_query, OBJECT );
```

**RESULT**
`<?php var_dump( $inbox_rows ); ?>` shows an:

> **`array`**
>    *`empty`*

**»** WHAT'S THE PROBLEM WITH MY QUERY?

#### References

- [LEFT JOIN, INNER OUTER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN is driving me crazy. Please help?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15385/left-join-inner-outer-join-left-outer-join-is-driving-me-crazy-please-help)
- [Querying Email Addresses for a List of Users with Same Last Name?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/querying-email-addresses-for-a-list-of-users-with-same-last-name)

Comment: What appear if you `var_dump( $inbox_query )`?

Comment: The first basic step in debugging a custom query is to make sure it has no syntax errors. After you performed `get_results()` you'll have the query string in `$wpdb->last_query`. You can output this and copy it to an SQL shell (phpMyAdmin or whatever you use) to try the query there.

Comment: @G.M. I mentioned that already in the "Result" section - empty array.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I said var dump the **query** not the result... that's the same thing said by *s1lv3r*

Comment: I already tried `echo $inbox_query` (same as @s1lv3r said: `$wpdb->last_query`, and same as G.M. said `var_dump( $inbox_query )`) - all shows a same result: `SELECT .id, .dt_usr_sent, .dt_usr_rcvd, .user_id, .post_id, .qty, .msg_user, .msg_admin, .price, .user_req_id FROM LEFT JOIN ON .id = .user_req_id` - all the tables' names are EMPTY! - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you define your custom table names.

Please try:

```
$wpdb->user_req = $wpdb->prefix . 'user_req';
```

and

```
$wpdb->user_req_admin = $wpdb->prefix . 'user_req_admin';
```

Comment: if I put the prefix hard coded like: `$wpdb->wp_user_req`, isn't that same to `$wpdb->prefix . 'user_req'`? I actually skipped the prefix part here in this question, but I mentioned them hard coded.